# What is calling the "index.html"(eventmenu.html)

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, ionic-framework

in this codepen -> http://codepen.io/auching/pen/vyzJg

i can not see anything "calling" the event-menu.html, i see the $stateProviderRoute, BUT nothing is provided in the start of the application, i have to click in some of the List item to change the URL, so the stateProvider can work using the URL, but the event-menu(start) never is called, so HOW it know that have to "start" the application in the event-menu

i can change all html codes in its own file, and leave in the index.html just this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">       
      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
```

but in the MainCtrl, there is nothing saying ex:

```
onload="startApplicationCallingTheEventMenu.html()">
```

sorry if its a confuse, i just need to get this point so i can start working with $routes

Answer (score 0):

not very familiar with the ionic-framework but I think it works as follows.

on start it seems to  call $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");

/event, loading event-menu.html, which contains

`<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>`

and /home, which loads home.html in the ion-nav-view with the name: menuContent